# Setting Up Dual Monitor with High Resolution on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, resolution

I am on Windows 10 and I am trying to set up two monitors.

- [LG 27UD58](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-27UD58-B-4k-uhd-led-monitor)
- [Dell U2720Q](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/ultrasharp-27-4k-usb-c-monitor-u2720q/apd/210-avjv/monitors-monitor-accessories)

The letters on my Dell monitor are sharp and clear. However, the letters on my LG monitor are not great.

I get a warning on my LG monitor that the recommended resolution of `3840 x 2160` couldn't be set. Instead, the resolution is set to `2560 x 1440`.

However, if I turn off my "Dell monitor", the resolution on my LG monitor goes to 3840 x 2160 and everything looks perfect.

How can I fix this?

Comment: are you using "extend desktop" option or "project to another monitor"?

Comment: I choose the "extend desktop". As there are two monitors, how can I choose the "duplicate/project" option?

Comment: what device/graphics card/etc are you using? And what kind of connection (HDMI, DisplayPort, etc) and what version of the connector? It is possible that your device can't push such a high resolution, and can only do 1440p on 2 monitors or 4k on 1, for example.